# CGPDFScanner and Adobe-Japan1

Tags: ios, pdf, cgpdf

I'm using `CGPDFScanner` to extract text from a PDF.

At the time my `TJ` operator callback is called, the current font has `CIDSystemInfo->Registry` value "Adobe" and `CIDSystemInfo->Ordering` value "Japan1". i.e. character set "Adobe-Japan1".

How do I use this fact to convert all the text I've found with the `Tj` operator to unicode?

I'm sure I'm not seeing the wood for the trees here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe's CMAP files to re-map Japan1 to unicode. Also look at the "Supplement" to get the correct file.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cmap/Downloads